# Signature validation fails when SAML token is passed back from identity provider using WS-Federation authentication (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, saml-2.0, ws-federation

**Context**

I am implementing an ASP.NET Core web application that uses cookie and WS-Federation authentication (it uses the cookie if it's there and works, otherwise it asks the identity provider for a SAML token if the user is signed in). I've done this in .NET without too many issues, but now that I'm moving over to ASP.NET Core I'm dealing with some bizarre and frustrating problems.

**Error**

The specific problem I'm dealing with now is when the SAML token is passed back to my application and is validated. When it tries to validate the token, I get the following error:

> IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey , KeyId: 
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey , KeyId: 
>   '.
>   Exceptions caught:
>    'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml.XmlValidationException: IDX30207: SignatureMethod is not supported: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'. CryptoProviderFactory: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory'.
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml.Signature.Verify(SecurityKey key, CryptoProviderFactory cryptoProviderFactory)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml.XmlValidationException: IDX30207: SignatureMethod is not supported: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'. CryptoProviderFactory: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory'.
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml.Signature.Verify(SecurityKey key, CryptoProviderFactory cryptoProviderFactory)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
>   '.
>   token: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityToken'.

I think the key part is that it says

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml.XmlValidationException: IDX30207: SignatureMethod is not supported: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'

This signature method is taken from the SAML token. It's in the `SignedInfo` node of the XML tree in the following element `<SignatureMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1\" />`.

**Relevant code**

In `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`, the relevant parts are

```
// code not shown here that sets up cookie authentication options

authBuilder.AddRemoteScheme<WsFederationOptions, WsFederationHandler>(WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, WsFederationDefaults.DisplayName, options =>
{
    options.Wtrealm = wtrealm;
    options.Wreply = wreply;
    options.SignOutWreply = wreply;
    byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("b34426428129de85a0b83e9320a290b32e09"); //not the actual key
    var symmetricKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes);

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        ValidIssuer = issuer,
        IssuerSigningKeys = new List<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey>() { symmetricKey }
    };

    var config = new WsFederationConfiguration
    {
        TokenEndpoint = issuer,
        Issuer = endpoint,
        SigningCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(symmetricKey, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
    };

    config.SigningKeys.Add(symmetricKey);
    options.Configuration = config;

    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler();
    options.SecurityTokenHandlers.Clear();
    options.SecurityTokenHandlers.Add(tokenHandler);

});
```

**The issue (potentially)**

There are several differences between how I originally implemented the .NET version and this .NET Core version, however I feel like there is one in particular that could be causing the error:

In the .NET Core version I have to specify `WsFederationConfiguration.SigningCredentials`. I didn't have to specify that in the .NET version. The reason why this may be the issue is that I define the `SigningCredentials` as

```
    SigningCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(symmetricKey, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
```

I'm not entirely sure how it works, but I believe the security algorithm specified by the second parameter (in this case the argument is `SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256`) is supposed to correspond to the signature method specified by the SAML token (I pointed this out in the error above). I checked the list of security algorithms in `SecurityAlgorithms`, and there aren't any corresponding to http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1 or RSA with SHA1. I'm not even sure what HmacSha256 is, but whichever one I choose gives this error.

I believe the reason why I didn't specify this in the .NET version is that I made my own security token handler which inherits `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler`, and the only difference is that I override the `ValidateToken` method. I tried doing the same in the .NET Core version, but this is creating a whole new set of problems, particularly DLLs not loading at run time (I think it's another version of the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` vs `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` problem... sigh).

Sorry for the long post. Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Comment: The lack of sha1 support is likely intentional, it's extremely outdated and insecure.

Comment: @Tratcher Hmm yeah, unfortunately (or fortunately) that may be the case. I'll see if I can just get the ClaimsPrincipal without validating for testing purposes until the identity provider changes the algorithm.